# How to create the Delegate Design Pattern within an Xcode Playground in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocols, swift-playground

I encountered some kind of a problem while using a **Swift Playground** and trying to set up a simple **Delegate Design**.

> The problem seems to be the fact, **that protocols can not be marked as public** but the **source folder in a Playground is considered as a new Module**. Therefore I can't find a solution for this problem.

Here is my code so far ***(IN THE SOURCE FOLDER, THE VIEWCONTROLLER IS IN THE PLAYGROUND FILE)***

```swift
//MARK: - Imports
import UIKit

//MARK: - Protocols
protocol UIManagerDelegate {
    func didChangePage(forward: Bool)
}

//MARK: - Properties & Initialisers
public class UIManager {

    // Properties
    private let parentView : UIView
    private var delegate: UIManagerDelegate

    // Initialisers
    public init(for view: UIView, delegate: UIManagerDelegate) {

        self.parentView = view
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

> The error message I get is the following: **Initializer cannot be declared public because its parameter uses an internal type.** And when trying to mark the protocol as public, this also produces an error.

Do you guys have any idea on how to fix this issue?
Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your original question, but we generally define our protocols to be `class` protocols (e.g. `protocol UIManagerDelegate: class { ... }`) and make the `delegate` property a `weak` reference (e.g. `private weak var delegate: UIManagerDelegate?`). Strong references to delegate objects is a really easy was to introduce strong reference cycles.

Comment: I’d also recommend against using `UI` prefix as that is intended for UIKit symbols and your use of it is likely to be a source of confusion in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the delegate public

```
public protocol UIManagerDelegate
```

Comment: Thanks, this works now but when I tried this before, I got an error message telling me that protocols can not be marked as public. Do you have any idea why this error message popped up?

Comment: Probably you made the function public not the class.

Comment: Maybe, thanks a lot for your help. Now its working;)